# APCluster Error in as.vector(data): no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Tags: r, r-s4, coerce

Using an unclustered input data frame (fci), an APResult is created from apcluster() as epxected:

```
> apclr2q02 <- apcluster(negDistMat(r=2), fci)
> show(apclr2q02)

APResult object

Number of samples     =  1045 
Number of iterations  =  826 
Input preference      =  -22.6498 
Sum of similarities   =  -1603.52 
Sum of preferences    =  -1336.338 
Net similarity        =  -2939.858 
Number of clusters    =  59
```

The online [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apcluster/apcluster.pdf) says that aggExCluster() can accept either data to be clustered as input, or a previous clustering result (ExClust or APResult).  Running aggExCluster on the unclustered data (fci), the code works as expected:

```
> aglomr2 <- aggExCluster(negDistMat(r=2), fci)
> aglomr2

AggExResult object

Number of samples          =  1045 
Maximum number of clusters =  1045
```

The result can be plotted in dendogram format and all is well; however, using the APResult obtained above (apclr2q02) as input, the following error is returned:

```
> aglomr2 <- aggExCluster(negDistMat(r=2), apclr2q02)
Error in as.vector(data) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Any suggestions about what I might be doing wrong with the APResult object as input?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `aggExCluster()` on top of a previous clustering result given as an '`ExClust`' or '`APResult`' object, these objects need to be passed as argument '`x`' and, additionally, the similarity matrix needs to be available. Here is a self-contained code snippet on the basis of your example (note that the object '`apres`' returned from `apcluster()` includes the similarity matrix):

```
cl1 <- cbind(rnorm(50,0.2,0.05),rnorm(50,0.8,0.06))
cl2 <- cbind(rnorm(50,0.7,0.08),rnorm(50,0.3,0.05))
x <- rbind(cl1,cl2)

apres <- apcluster(negDistMat(r=2), x, q=0.7)
aggExCluster(x=apres)
```

In case that you start from a similarity matrix, you can either include it in the 'APResult' object, i.e.

```
sim <- negDistMat(r=2, x)
apres <- apcluster(sim, q=0.7, includeSim=TRUE)
aggExCluster(x=apres)
```

(if `apcluster()` is called on a similarity matrix, the matrix is not included in the result object by default, which can be overridden with '`includeSim=TRUE`')

Alternatively, you can also specify the similarity matrix via the argument '`s`':

```
sim <- negDistMat(r=2, x)
apres <- apcluster(sim, q=0.7)
aggExCluster(x=apres, s=sim)
```

Calling `aggExCluster()` with a similarity function and an '`APResult`' object will not work because the '`APResult`' does not include the original data, so `aggExCluster()` is unable to compute the similarity matrix that is necessary for clustering. Instead, if `aggExCluster()` 
is called with argument '`s`' being a similarity function, it expects the argument '`x`' to contain the raw data and will therefore try to convert it to a subsettable object. That is why you get this error message.

Comment: Ausgezeichnet, vielen Dank! (Excellent, many thanks!)  That worked with my data as well.